# Setting multiple variables in the same time using tasks with methods

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I have three **double** variables and I am using the same method to set them up, and I want to set them all at the same time using **Tasks**.

Here's what it looks like now:

```
double a = InputValidators.InputConverter(txtA.text);
double b = InputValidators.InputConverter(txtB.text);
double c = InputValidators.InputConverter(txtC.text);
```

How to use the method for all three of them at the same time using **Tasks**??

And I am using C# .NET 4.5 if it helps.

Comment: What you mean by `at the same time`?

Comment: This is overkill using a separate task to read text box value

Comment: its not overkill because the method those a lot more advanced action then just converting the text, he does check the text, then splits it, converts every part, use math functions to connect all the converted parts and returns the final value

Comment: @DavidS47 no, it's still overkill. Any computer made in the last two decades (if not more) can do string and math operations really quickly. What'll actually be slower is spinning off threads and multitasking. Threads don't magically make things faster.

Answer (score 2):

This will run the three tasks asynchronously.  There is no control over when they actually start or in what order.  See [Task Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx)

```
Func<string, double> func = str => InputValidators.InputConverter(str);

Task<double> t1 = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => func(txtA.text));
Task<double> t2 = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => func(txtB.text));
Task<double> t3 = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => func(txtC.text));

double a = t1.Result;
double b = t2.Result;
double c = t3.Result;
```

Comment: What is clear is that they will NOT be "run at the same time", isn't it? Other thing is parallel execution but for that you have to know all the information (for example: the elements in a loop).

Comment: @varocarbas, absolutely, this depends on TaskScheduler decision but definitely not in the same time

Comment: @varocarbas I'm assuming this is a long running function and they are supposed to be run asynchronously.  I did put that they will not actually start simultaneously in my answer.

Comment: Task<double> t1 = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => func(txtA.text)); is not exactly what i need but its close, you see in my code i return each of the function to a value like "double a = thefunction(txtA.Text);" but the way you did it, it does not put it in a value and i need it to.

Comment: @DavidS47 The result of the Task<TResult> is stored in the Result property.  I have updated my answer to get assign the values.  This will wait for the asynchronous task to complete before assigning.